# Javascript Menu to Show 1 image and hide another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple menu bar for displaying a couple different menus. When I click the first one the image comes up, but when I click the 2nd I need the 1st one to disappear and the 2nd appear in its place.

What happens right now is I click "Main Menu" and it opens, but then I need to click it again to close it.

```
<div class='rmm' data-menu-style = "graphite" data-menu-title = "Menu">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="hideshow('main_menu')">Main Menu Show</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="hideshow('gluten_friendly')">Gluten Friendly</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="hideshow('kids_menu')">Kids Menu</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="main_menu" style="display:none;"><a href="http://xxxxxx"></div>
<div id="gluten_friendly" style="display:none;"><a href="http://xxxxx"></div>
<div id="kids_menu" style="display:none;"><a href="http://xxxxx"></div>
```

=====Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function hideshow(temp){
    var menu = document.getElementById(temp);
    if (menu.style.display=="block")
       menu.style.display="none"
    else
       menu.style.display="block"
    return false;
}
</script>
```

I've updated the code from Sid, which works a little better than what I had, but when I click "Main Menu" it opens and I still need to click it again to close, but also when I click "Kids Menu" that one opens right below the "Main Menu".

I know I'm getting close, haha, ughh.

This is part of my Company Website so I don't really want to post the link in public, but if someone can help me please shoot me an email and I will send you the live link so you can see what I'm dealing with. It would be greatly appreciated and I'll gladly make note of the help here on the forum.

seansugden@britishbeer.com

Comment: The following 'main menu', 'gluten friendly', 'kids menu' are **not** valid `id`'s.

Comment: How about something like "#main"

Comment: Avoid to use any special characters and spaces for your ID attribute. You can use special characters though but don't include them unnecessarily. Spaces are not at all practiced for ID attribute in html

Comment: Any id attribute would look like this `<a id='main'>Foo</a>`. In CSS, yes the selector is `#main`, but in JS you are looking at `document.getElementById('main')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following may not be the best solution but works OK for me.

HTML

```
<div class='rmm' data-menu-style = "graphite" data-menu-title = "Menu" >
  <ul>
    <li><a href="javascript:hideshow(document.getElementById('main_menu'))">Main Menu Show</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:hideshow(document.getElementById('gluten_friendly'))">Gluten Friendly</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:hideshow(document.getElementById('kids_menu'))">Kids Menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:hideshow(document.getElementById('desserts'))">Desserts</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="main_menu"><a href="http://xxxxxxx"><img src="http://xxxxxx" height="650" width="650"></div>
<div id="gluten_friendly"><a href="http://xxxxxxx"><img src="http://xxxxxx" height="650" width="650"></div>
<div id="kids_menu"><a href="http://xxxxxxx"><img src="http://xxxxxx" height="650" width="650"></div>
<div id="desserts"><a href="http://xxxxxxx"><img src="http://xxxxxx" height="650" width="650"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
function hideshow(temp){
    var menu = temp.id;

    if (menu == "main_menu") {
        document.getElementById('main_menu').style.display="block";
    }
    else
    {
       document.getElementById('main_menu').style.display="none";
    }

    if (menu == "gluten_friendly") {
        document.getElementById('gluten_friendly').style.display="block";
    }
    else
    {
       document.getElementById('gluten_friendly').style.display="none";
    }

    if (menu == "kids_menu") {
        document.getElementById('kids_menu').style.display="block";
    }
    else
    {
       document.getElementById('kids_menu').style.display="none";
    }

    if (menu == "desserts") {
        document.getElementById('desserts').style.display="block";
    }
    else
    {
       document.getElementById('desserts').style.display="none";
    }

}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/digiman07/e8ygV/)

Comment: this works exactly the way I needed it to! Agreed it may not be the cleanest code, but at least it's doing what I need. Thank you very much for this!

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar on my website. You need to give them all a class and do the following when one is clicked:

```
$('#desserts').click(function(){
    $('.menus').hide();
    $('#desserts').show();
});
```

When you click desserts, first all menus are closed, then desserts is opened. I don't completely understand what you want to show and hide but I'm sure you'll be able to adapt it.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but unclear on how to apply this? Can you give me a short example of the usage?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is when the user clicks "Main Menu" an image of a menu appears. Then when the user clicks "Kids Menu" the "Main Menu" disappears and the "Kids Menu" is now shown. 
What's happening is the menus are appearing but they're being stacked, so "Main" is first, then "Kids" is below that, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try using underscores `_` or dashes `-` instead of spaces for the `id` attributes. As Brett said in his comment, the ones with spaces are invalid.

As for hiding them all, you can give the `div`s a common class

```
<div class="image" id="main-menu"> ... </div>
```

and use `document.getElementsByClassName('class-name')` to retrieve an array to loop over and hide (before showing the selected one).

```
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('image');
for(var i in divs){
    div.style.display = 'none';
}
```